# IAT Hooking questions?

Tags: malware, defense, detection, api

I have researched IAT hooking by malware and i still have a few questions:

1. If the IAT of the program in memory is different to the IAT of the static program (before it has been ran) does this imply a api hook?
2. How are these detected i have read the question here: [What are the methods to find hooked functions and APIs?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/what-are-the-methods-to-find-hooked-functions-and-apis) but i am still confused could you please provide a basic step by step explaination?
3. Is there legitimate uses for api hooking other than antiviruses which could lead to false posatives in a detection tool?

Comment: 1. How are you reading the IAT? A Rootkit that hooks functions could return the correct IAT when requested; therefore hiding the presence of the hooks.

Comment: That's gave me something to think about would windows apis be secure against this ?

Comment: Detection of a rootkit that advanced would probably require a kernel mode program. No, hooking functions in this manner is what rootkit developers are doing.

Comment: Ok I was more interested in basic detection then build my knowledge to more advanced detection. But how would a kernal mode program be made?

Comment: A well written kernel mode rootkit would be undetectable on normal hardware. Kernel programs/drivers can be written using the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

Comment: Ok thanks but how would a less advanced rootkit be detected

Comment: A legitimate program that uses hooks is Proxifier

Answer (score 1):

Detecting a rootkit is by nature difficult, this is because rootkits often employ methods to evade detection. A well written rootkit ought to be undetectable.
However, rootkits that are badly coded may leave traces of their activity in the system (failing to delete logs etc).

- Unsigned Dynamic Link Libraries Loaded into (all) processes
- Random code checksums
- General malware detection methods

Also see: https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-06/bh-eu-06-Rutkowska.pdf